# Eclipse RCP Target Platform: Bundle 'org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed' cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, rcp, target-platform

I just created my first target platform and ran into a problem:

> The Bundle org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed cannot be resolved.

My target platform has one location:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
    Eclipse Platform Launchers
    Eclipse RCP SDK
```

I set this as my target platform and validated plug-ins in the run configurations. In the run configurations there is no bundle called org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed so I cannot activate it.

I am sorry if this is an easy and stupid question but I am new to target platforms (I added my whole workspace every time as my target platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed` is not included in the Features you have added to your target platform.

Simply add the feature *Eclipse Platform SDK* to the target platform:

- select your location, and click *Edit*,
- filter for "Eclipse Platform SDK",
- select the feature,
- *delete the text in the filter**,
- and click *Finish*.
- Wait until the Target Platform has resolved, then *save*, and set it as the target platform.

That should solve the issue.

It has taken me a good wee while to get my head around Target Platform, Run Configuration, etc., so keep your head up :).

**Otherwise, you will remove what you already have in the target platform (Platform Launchers and RCP SDK), and install only the Platform SDK. This is due to a bug.*

Comment: That helped, thank you! But how can you know which bundle is in which plugin / location?

Comment: @PhilippBüch. Very good question! AFAIK, there is no listing of any sort that shows which plug-in is included in which feature. I've had problems myself, locating plug-ins. Try googling for the plug-in name and look for tutorials amongst the search results, they may name the feature to include in order to get the plug-in. If anyone knows about a better way, *please post*!

Comment: @PhilippBüch: I've made this issue into [a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025599/how-to-find-out-which-feature-contains-a-needed-plug-in-on-an-eclipse-download-s) now, as there should be a better way for this, really.