# How to search Eclipse P2 repositories?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which feature contains a needed plug-in on an Eclipse download site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025599/how-to-find-out-which-feature-contains-a-needed-plug-in-on-an-eclipse-download-s)

I'm building an RCP application and am currently trying to define my target platform. I've configured a Software Site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) and selected the Package `Eclipse RCP SDK`.

Now I'm missing a few dependencies, for instance `org.eclipse.core.filesystem` and `org.eclipse.ui.ide`. However, I have no idea how to identify which package I have to include in my runtime.

Is there an aggregate search service for the Eclipse repository, analogous to http://search.maven.org/, that can tell me where I can find a specific package or bundle?

Comment: I'm implementing a search service analogous to `search.maven.org`. It is a prototype at present supporting searching fields with keywords. At the backend, I manually curate update sites in Microsoft Dataverse (Your suggestions for update sites to be added are welcome.) and trigger a workflow to get `content.jar` file, unzip, parse the content of an update site and append records to the database. I used Retool to build the frontend. Please give me feed back if you can. You can try it at https://gedobu.retool.com/embedded/public/5d6c8b4d-b43e-4f23-9f21-d82111d3abb0

Answer (score 0):

Please see a similar question at [How to find out which feature contains a needed plug-in on an Eclipse download site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025599/how-to-find-out-which-feature-contains-a-needed-plug-in-on-an-eclipse-download-s), and the answers there.

There's a fairly complicated way to achieve this posted on [this blog](http://divby0.blogspot.com/2010/10/howto-find-feature-that-contains-plugin.html), but generally the answer to your question is: No there isn't such a thing (yet).