# How to search for a feature in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Hi I have a feature in eclipse and when I open the `feature.xml` file it requires another feature.

The problem:

I can't find this feature, is there a way to search for it or to let Eclipse show me the location?

Comment: Usually the feature id gives you a clue. For example `org.eclipse.emf.xxxxx` is part of Eclipse EMF.

Comment: @greg-449 True, but there should be a functionality to search for it.

Comment: `Help > install new software` will find features on any available update site if told to do so but I am not aware of anything that will just show you a location.

Comment: @greg-449 The feature in case is already installed in my local eclipse somewhere. I just need to find it. Actually I found it now, it is in the target definition, but there should be a functionality for this, instead of me having to search manually.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Your target definition *is* the place to look for what features are available; the .target editor has filtering/searching capability. So what, exactly, are you looking for that isn't provided?

Comment: @E-Riz Features can also be defined in the workspace. But even if you consider only the target definition, in my specific case Im looking for feature A, when I open the target definition, I only find features B, C, D, E, F, G. All of those in turn contain other features. I finally managed to find the feature I was looking for, namely A, included in one of those. But I had to manually search for it. The filtering in the target editor only works for the top level,  so it won't help you if the feature you are looking for is not a top level feature. I'm using eclipse Kepler btw.